# How to round the confidence interval produced by the stats t interval to two decimal places

Tags: python, scipy.stats

I am finding the t confidence interval across rows of my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'nums_1': [1, 2, 3], 'nums_2': [1, 1, 5], 'nums_3' : [8,7,9]})    


df['CI']=df.apply(lambda row: stats.t.interval(0.95, len(df)-1, 
loc=np.mean(row), scale=stats.sem(row)), axis=1)
```

How can I get the confidence intervals given to me by scipy stats t interval to be rounded to two decimal places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.apply()` a lambda function that uses `np.round()` to two decimal places.

```
df["CI"] = df["CI"].apply(lambda x: np.round(x,2))
df
```

Output:

[image]